# No route was found that is identical to the URL and request method

Tags: permalinks, errors

I am getting the following error message in some plugins after a website move "No route was found that is identical to the URL and request method." I have already renewed the permal link structure but this does not lead to any solution, the error message comes in google SiteKit, FluentCRM. Is there already a solution for this?

best regards Chris

Comment: can you provide more information? Which plugins? Is it only on plugin URLs? Which URLs? Are you sure this isn't a problem specific to those plugins or a Google issue? Questions about plugins are offtopic here, and the question isn't the clearest, can you edit it to be clearer and provide more specifics?